# notificationCenter.postNotificationName(NotificationContactCreated, object: nil) fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error, nsnotificationcenter

I have this line of code that successfully runs on first got:

```
notificationCenter.postNotificationName(NotificationContactCreated, object: nil)
```

But later on when this same line in same function is called I get the `fatal error`:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Yet if I set through the code both notificationCenter and NotificationContactCreated are both set.

I'm going round in circles and cannot find the cause of this...

Any help ...please???

Thanks

here is the notification center:

```
  //
// notification center to be used across phone app
//
lazy var notificationCenter: NSNotificationCenter = {

    return NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
}()
```

here is the func where it gets called:

```
 func updateAccount(firstName: String, lastName: String, emailAddress: String, companyName: String, isSelf: Bool) -> Void {

    // we are going to update the Contacts entity
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityNameContacts)

    // filter on first name + last name + email address
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@ && lastName == %@ && emailAddress == %@", firstName, lastName, emailAddress)

    do {

        // try to get an array of accounts based on filter, should only be one returned
        let contactsArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Contacts]

        // if there is a record we just want to update it
        if contactsArray?.count > 0 {

            // grab the reading object
            let contact = contactsArray![0]

            // and update its data
            contact.firstName = firstName

            contact.lastName = lastName

            contact.emailAddress = emailAddress

            contact.companyName = companyName
        }
        else {

            // otherwise we need to insert a new record
            let newContact: Contacts =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityNameContacts, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Contacts

            // and populate with new data
            newContact.firstName = firstName

            newContact.lastName = lastName

            newContact.emailAddress = emailAddress

            newContact.companyName = companyName

            newContact.isSelf = isSelf
        }

        // write amends
        saveContext()

        self.notificationCenter.postNotificationName(NotificationContactCreated, object: nil)

    } catch {

        print("func updateAccount(firstName: String, lastName: String, emailAddress: String, companyName: String, isSelf: Bool) -> Void !!!ERROR")
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to post more code, that's not enough context to know what's going on.

Comment: It's probably related to the method that this code is in if its only happening there

Comment: I just tried with NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(NotificationContactCreated, object: nil) and same result...runs first time but subsequent calls bomb?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at the start of whatever method handles the `NotificationContactCreated` notification and see whether it executes?

Comment: I have, everything works in works in the method/func I posted.  It runs 1st time but next time round it fails?

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about the method that receives `NotificationContactCreated`, not the one that sends it.